# .NET Core DI Service Collection non modifiable service for integrity

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have been investing time into .NET core and the Dependency Injection model using the ServiceCollection object.

Is there any way to protect the integrity of the service implementations that have already been added to the collection?

I would like to know that the original implementation of a service I have added hasn't been modified or replaced at some point during runtime.

In the case of security, if I was an attacker who knew what I was doing and had a remote code execution vulnerability, I could replace a key service implementation and aim to hide with a form of persistence.

In the case of fool proofing, if I had a large project I would hate to have to go debugging why something went wrong to find out a developer replaces the implementation of a service that was in widespread use.

Any suggestions? Perhaps there is some protection that prevents this, or its just not a concern?

Comment: Once the service collection is built which creates the service provider, changes to the service collection have no effect on the provider resolving implementations.

Comment: From a security perspective, there is nothing you can do. If the the attacker is able to execute code on your machine, the machine should be considered compromized, and trying to detect changes will certainly not help; as the attacker already has unlimited access to your machine and your process. Trying to prevent changes to the ServiceCollection will, therefore, only give you a false sense of security.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `IServiceCollection` manually, defining a class, with a `List<ServiceDescriptor>` to implement all methods declared in the interfaces.

Then, modify the methods that may change the values of the items which are registries, adding notifying operations to determine whether the values are changed.